# Permission with tar command

Tags: linux, tar

[image]

[image]

I have some problem with linux "tar" command.I want to unzip a config001.gz to a directory(with owner root ,group root and 777 permission as show in pic).

My origin dir and target dir is shown in pic.
My question is:

- why there is en empty folder in a config001.gz file(I try to tar two file together and look in the the config002.tgz file ,there is no empty dir)?
- if I don't append --no-overwrite-dir after command,it will raise error, what permission does "tar" want to change?
- why --no-overwrite-dir option can fix the problem

my mount infomation:
fuse.mfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other 0 0

Comment: What filesystem are you unpacking into?

Comment: I try the experiment in ext4 and fuse.mfs, both show the error.@KamilCuk

Comment: Then what are the mount options. You can just post `mount` output or `cat /proc/mounts`. `tar` just can't change the time and permissions on the files. Can you do that as that user? `touch a.txt` `touch -a -t '12:12:12' a.txt` and maybe `chmod 000 a.txt` ?

Comment: Yes,my current user can change file permission,touch command is also ok.mount infomation has post

Comment: Please __do not post images of text__. It makes it impossible to copy the text and also it is really hard to see such posts on mobile devices. Don't post images of text or code. The best would be to reformat your post and include relevant info in code blocks. As a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why there is en empty folder in a config001.tgz file?

There is the "root folder" included in the tar archive. The folder the tar was in. The privileges, owner and group, permissions and creation/modification (or one of them, I am not sure) dates are included. You can create such archive with:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/a
cd /tmp/a
echo 123 > 1
echo 234 > 2
tar cfvp /tmp/test.tar .

# and inspect with:
tar -tvf ./test.tar 
drwxr-xr-x kamil/kamil       0 2019-07-15 12:50 ./
-rw-r--r-- kamil/kamil       4 2019-07-15 12:50 ./2
-rw-r--r-- kamil/kamil       4 2019-07-15 12:50 ./1
```

By specifing the `.`, ie. the current directory, the information about the current directory itself will be included in he `tar`. Ie. the information about the owner and group, permissions and dates.

> if I don't append --no-overwrite-dir after command,it will raise error, what permission does "tar" want to change?

`tar` wants to change the permissions of the directory you are inside. The `hpc_dir` directory. The `hpc_dir` is owned by `root`, so `tar` can't change/touch it.

> why --no-overwrite-dir option can fix the problem?

Because then `tar` sees the the currect directory `hpc_dir` exists. Because of that, `tar` doesn't try to create the directory, nor tries to change the owner and group permissions of the directory, nor tries to restore the creation date of the directory.

You could just go with `mkdir somedir; tar xzfv archive.tar -C somedir` - that way the `somedir` will be created by current user, so `tar` will be able to change it's properties.

Or you could just change the owner of `hpc_dir` directory, letting your user modify it.